# How to resize a bitmap

Tags: c

```
    // determine padding for scanlines
int padding =  (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
{
    for(int q = 0; q < n; q++)
    {
        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            // write RGB triple to outfile
            for (int r = 0; r < n; r++)
                fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);

        }

    // skip over padding, if any
    fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

    //then add it back (to demonstrate how)
    for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
        fputc(0x00, outptr);
   }
}
```

I'm trying to alter code so that I can resize a bmp by a factor of n (adding n triples to the the width and the height).  I have found a way to iterate a for loop that will resize the width: `for (int r = 0; r < n; r++)`.   I tried to do the same thing with height and I can't figure out why it won't work.  `for (int q = 0; q < n; q++)`

Comment: Please clarify your intention. "resize by factor of n" and "adding n pixels to width and height" are different things.

Comment: the code provided seem to copy pixel data as it is. Any resizing would definitely require to load the entire rectangular matrix of pixels into memory, proceed with the geometry operations and then dump the resulting matrix (possibly of different dimensions) to the output file, respecting the output format.

Comment: I apologize--it should be adding n pixels to width and height, not resizing by a factor of n.

Comment: what would be the position of new pixels among old pixels? what would be their values?

Comment: If n=3, I would ideally to have 3 copies of each pixel on each row for each pixel in the original.  Then I would want to have 3 copies of each row.  So if n=3, there would be 9 copies of each original pixel in the new image.  Right now, the program adjusts the width, but does not copy the rows multiple times over, so the height remains the same, resulting in really distorted pictures.  (Note:  this program should only make images larger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the line level you should after single read of a pixel do `n` writes of it. This is done by adding another inner loop. That copied pixel resides at `triple` var during the operation.

At the file level you should repeatedly process single line, reading and writing it multiple times.

If your input file is on the disk, it should support rewinding. So you can read the line, write it (duplicating pixels inside, as shown above), then rewind the file to the start of the line, read the line again, write it, etc.

Try to store the file position with `ftell` before reading the line, and rewind the file position to this point with `fseek` each time you need to process it.

Comment: Hallelujah! It took me forever to figure out the how and why, but you were absolutely right. The program works beautifully now.