# CS50 course pset5: scale bitmap in C

Tags: c, bitmap, scale, stretch, cs50

I'm doing CS50 course online and I need to scale a bitmap. I can stretch it horizontally but what is causing me troubles is how to stretch it vertically. I double the size of the image in resolution but stretch happens only in bottom half of the image and the upper half of the image is blank white. I already tried to search for fseek on reddit and here but can't figure out why the image stretches only horizontally.

This is part of my code:

```
n = 2; // scale up by factor 2
bi.biWidth = bi.biWidth * n; // double width
bi.biHeight = bi.biHeight * n; //double hight

//iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
{

    for (int m = 0 ; m < n; m++) // repeat process n-times to copy lines vertically
    {

        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage for RGB values to be copied
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            // write RGB triple to outfile n-times to stretch horizontally
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }
        }

        fseek(inptr, -sizeof(bi.biWidth), SEEK_CUR); // go back to the beginning of the line

    }
}
```

Comment: It might be simpler to read the entire row into RAM, manipulate the data in RAM, then write it back out from RAM. That way you don't have to mess with seeking at all.

Comment: This was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569217/newbie-resizing-a-bitmap).

Answer (score 1):

You need to fseek by the *unscaled* width to rewind a line from the original (unscaled) file. For that matter, you need to iterate over the original dimensions, too.

Also, `sizeof` probably isn't doing what you want. It will yield the size of the `biWidth` variable itself (presumably an integer, so probably 32bits, so `sizeof(int)` will yield 4). Remove the `sizeof`.

Comment: and don't use `sizeof`

Answer (score 0):

that was really needed, but I'm sure there will be more elegant solution

```
int oWidth = bi.biWidth; //store original width
int oHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); //store original height
bi.biWidth = bi.biWidth * n;
bi.biHeight = bi.biHeight * n;    
.
.
.
if (m < n-1)
{
    fseek(inptr, -(oWidth*3), SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Comment: The `3` looks suspicious. ... Oh. It's the size of the rgb triple. That should be a `#define`d constant or `enum` constant.