# How does fwrite work?

Tags: c, fwrite

I'm trying to write a program in C that scales bitmap images by a given factor, when I use `fwrite()` inside a loop to do so:

```
// Go through each pixel of input bitmap
for (int y = 0; y < inWidth; y++)
{
    fread(pixel, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inBMP);

    // Write each pixel to output bitmap (factor) times
    for (int z = 0; z < factor; z++)
    {
        fwrite(pixel, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outBMP);
    }
}
```

Everything works:

[image: Input Bitmap] → [image: Output Bitmap]

But when I use `fwrite()` without a loop:

```
// Go through each pixel of input bitmap
for (int y = 0; y < inWidth; y++)
{
    fread(pixel, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inBMP);

    // Write each pixel to output bitmap (factor) times
    fwrite(pixel, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), factor, outBMP);
}
```

I get this:

[image: Output Bitmap]

Why does that happen ?

Comment: because the in the header you have the same size of the image, but body has more information

Comment: In your second case you are only reading 1 `RGBTRIPLE` but you are writing `factor` `RGBTRIPLE`s

Comment: is this [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569217/how-to-resize-a-bitmap).

Comment: I appreciate your help guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the third parameter, `count`, indicates how many elements are in the array pointed to by `ptr`, not how many times the instance pointed to as `ptr` should be written. You're basically writing garbage that's in memory behind what's `ptr` is pointing to.

See the [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i understand now why i get that result !